# How to move a VM/VM's from an inaccessible Datastore to a different datastore in VMware vCenter?

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vcenter

So there is this VM on datastores in my firms VMware vCenter infra and the datastore has been inaccessible, but there are VM's which needs to be in use on that datastore, my task is to migrate them to a different datastore, how can this be done. what should I do for the VM to be on a different datastore.

I have already tried re scanning the datastore but it won't give me a solution.